# How can a web-app prevent the host computer from entering sleep mode?

Tags: javascript, multimedia

I wrote a workout timer web app (beeps and all), but my computer goes to sleep while it is running, defeating the purpose. I notice it doesn't sleep when watching YouTube. I'm guessing this is because the computer won't sleep during media playback? Is there a way to do something in the background while the timer is running so that it remains visible on the screen without going to sleep?

Comment: [This site](https://nosleep.page/) explains how they do it.

Comment: Most solutions, like [NoSleep.js](https://richtr.github.io/NoSleep.js/), play a tiny background video. Yet, you should also review the the [issues](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js/issues) before using.  You might also consider how this might affect battery usage on mobile devices.